# How can I use inner join to display two matching columns that correlate themselves in a third table by other two columns?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have the following tables in SQL:

---

students:

```
primary key: student_id
name
email
```

---

courses:

```
primary key: course_id    
name
```

---

registration:

```
primary key: registration_id
start_date    
foreign key: student_id    
foreign key: course_id
```

---

What I want: Sql to display a table that correlates **students names** with **course names**, like this:

```
student name | course name    
john         | computer science    
alex         | architecture    
daisy        | engineering
```

I heard that I need to use Inner join to do this.

Comment: Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "correlates" means nothing in particular. Clarity is need to characterize, solve & communicate problems. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. What parts are you able to do? Where are you stuck? Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` is indeed what is required:

```
SELECT s.name, c.name
FROM students s
JOIN registration r ON r.student_id = s.student_id
JOIN courses c ON c.course_id = r.course_id
```

Here's a small [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e85e6329a3d6df32c709e269e3819173)...

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed what I needed to do. You even made a demo out of it!
Still, I'm very new to sql, so could you please explain me what each line does? From my poor understanding, it seens like you're combining all the three tables in one by joining them togheter, which probably isn't the case since you used the select command in two tables instead of just one.

Comment: @enricogp you are right, I am making the three tables into one with the `JOIN`s. We need to use all three tables to get your desired data because the `registration` table is required to link student names with the courses they have registered for. So the first line simply says what data we want to output (`name` from each of the `student` and `courses` tables), then the next three lines tell MySQL how to create the bigger table out of the three others. I use aliases (`s`, `r` and `c`) just to shorten the query and make it easier to read. Have a play with the demo (try `SELECT *` instead)...